# Vi/Vim restore opened files

Tags: vi, vim

I was wondering if this common IDE feature is available.

Suppose I open many files using Vim, using `vsplit` and `split`. Then, I close everything.

The next day, I want to recover those files. That is, recover the way they were opened, not having to open each one (using `split` and `vsplit`) again.

Is that possible?

UPDATE:

Using `mksession!` and `source` commands, mapping commands in `.vimrc` file, is there a way to parameterize mappings so as to write a specific file?

for example:

```
map <F2> :mksession! ~/vim_session @INSERT_HERE<cr> "Save session to @INSERTHERE file
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can map using :mksession and :source to a set of keys for easy saving and restoring. Here's an example from my .vimrc that uses F2 and F3:

```
map <F2> :mksession! ~/vim_session <cr> " Quick write session with F2
map <F3> :source ~/vim_session <cr>     " And load session with F3
```

Comment: consider naming the file ~/.vim_session, too, so it's out of the way. this is more consistent with its function, too.

Comment: Holy crap this is excellent information.  Seems every year I learn even more vim awesomeness.  I'd also suggest automating this so that a keystroke saves your session and exits (like a traditional IDE) and your .vimrc auto-sources ~/.vimsession.

Comment: I lost syntax highlighting after reloading session?

Comment: If you're doing software development, it would be more in line with the way IDEs work, to have a separate session file for each project that you switch between.

Answer (score 11):

Give a look at the [`:mksession`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#:mksession) command, to create a [`session`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#views-sessions):

> A Session keeps the Views for all
>   windows, plus the global settings. 
>   You can save a Session and when you
>   restore it later the window layout
>   looks the same. You can use a Session
>   to quickly switch between different
>   projects, automatically loading the
>   files you were last working on in that
>   project.

Answer (score 4):

The best approach I've found is to use the vim-session plugin, http://github.com/xolox/vim-session which can be installed by adding:

```
Plugin 'xolox/vim-session'
```

to your .vimrc, followed by:

```
:PluginInstall
```

This plugin supports multiple sessions: you identify a session by name and then manage it with that name. Sessions can be added, deleted, updated, listed, ...

I've been using it for several months now; highly recommended.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using [GNU Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen). In short: it's a command line Window Manager that allows a user to access multiple separate terminal sessions inside a single terminal session. The main advantage to me is that you can detach the session, close your terminal window, and later re-attach the session, and continue working.

Comment: With most terminal emulaters it is enough to just close terminal window, screen handles this normally. I put `exec screen -m zsh` enclosed by condition that prevents launching screen inside screen into my zshrc.

Comment: or he might use tmux... it has a few more features. screen's features are a subset of tmux

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in this book:

http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/Vim#Download

It's one of the first few things they show you as an example of how great Vim is. ;)

Also, `<cr>` stands for Carriage Return.

Comment: Thanks, realized about the <cr> about 10 seconds after asking :p

Answer (score 1):

SessionMan http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2010
offers easier functionality. Be careful with miniBufExplorer. It's incompatible unless you use the modified version made by andrew on vim_use (and even then, it's only halfway compatible)

Answer (score 1):

My solution is as below, put them in .vimrc file. HTH.

```
" session related.
" Default session is located `~/.session_'. The suffix `_' is a dirty
" solution, just like the one-element tuple `(tuple_eliment,)' in Python..
cnoremap <C-O> source ~/.session_
cnoremap <C-S> mksession! ~/.session_
nnoremap <silent> <C-S><C-S> :mksession! ~/.session_ <CR>
```

Seems to be more complex, but very useful if you have multiple sessions to save and load.

P.S.
Here, I adopt the familiar `<Ctrl-S>` and `<Ctrl-O>` shortcuts, to save and load sessions. IMHO, this is more comfortable than reaching out my hand to `<Fn>` key. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [vim-obsession](https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession). It is much better than the default `mksession` as it stays out of your while still doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on hgmnz's answer and expanding for the update.

You can drop the `<cr>` from the mapping and this will put you into command mode to finish the command.

```
map <F2> :mksession! ~/<will stop here and you can type>
```

*When going in the command mode you can type % then press tab and it will expand to the current file's absolute path, you can also type %:p:h and press tab to expand to the current file's directory.*

You can also save each session to the working directory and by using local buffer directories you can have multiple sessions for working directories.

```
map <F2> :mksession! ./.vim_sessions <cr> " Will save session to current buffers directory.
map <F3> :source ./.vim_sessions <cr>
:lcd " Changes the current's buffer directory
```

Also be careful with reloading sessions as it does unload all current loaded buffers (http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#%3Amksession)

> 3. Unloads all currently loaded buffers.